# AXP209 : Usage without ACIN?

Tags: power-supply, power, lipo, android

I'm currently bulding and Android device and I've got a question which can't get answered.

The AXP209 is an IPS and power manager. It allow the usage and charge of a standard lipo.

It has two inputs : ACIN and USB VBUS. In a case of a tablet, will the IPS use VBUS to charge the battery and make the whole thing work, or is ACIN needed ?

[Datasheet](http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/AXP/AXP209_Datasheet_v1.0en.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever; After some deeper search into the datasheet, I've found this :

> The AXP209 power input can come from lithium battery (BAT),USB VBUS Input, external power
>   supply (ACIN). The IPS will select an appropriate power source depending on the battery and external
>   power conditions.
>
> O When only the battery is available, no external power input, the battery powers the system;
>
> O When there is a valid external power source(VBUS Or ACIN), is is the preferred power supply.
>
> O When the external power is removed, the IPS will seamlessly switch over to battery power.
>
> O When both VBUS and ACIN are available, ACIN will be used to power the system and recharge
>   the lithium battery;
>
> O If the ACIN cannot provide sufficient current, VBUS is also connected to source more
>   current;
>
> O If the drive capacity is still insufficient, then the charge current is reduced to zero, the
>   battery is used to power the system

So in the case of the AXP209 IPS, the order is **ACIN > VBUS > BAT**. When one of it fails, by delivering not enough power or by simply being absent, the IPS chooses a better supply seamlessly.

The answer to the question is **yes** then, the IPS can be used without *ACIN*,

Edit : and **yes** I'm sorry not looking deep enough and answering my dump question by myself

Comment: Self answers are considered appropriate. They build up answers for anyone Googling the same problem.